# Узнать сигнатуру функции, переданную через указатель

Tags: c++, указатели

Есть функция, принимающая указатель на функцию. Пусть это будет, `void f(void(*)());`.

**Вопрос:** Как узнать сигнатуру функции, адрес которой хранит указатель, или, как еще можно сказать, как различить две разные функции, переданные через этот указатель?

Если возможно, то желательно решить эту задачу в рамках C++14 и в рантайме

Comment: Если только не писать сигнатуры руками в таблицу, то в рамках *стандартного* С++ - никак. Да и, интересно знать, *зачем* - допустим, что это можно. Что это вам даст?...

Comment: Просто интересно, для саморазвития. И если явно сигнатуру узнать нельзя, то, на мой взгляд, все еще остается возможность сравнить две разных сигнатуры

Comment: Сигнатура функции является частью типа указателя, то бишь `(void) -> void` в данном случае. Если две функции разные, то и указатели будут разные.

Comment: Сравнить два разных указателя. А вообще, в чем смысл передачи указателя на функцию с иной сигнатурой (при этом еще и придется извратиться, чтоб компилятор такое пропустил) - с другим набором параметров - если это автоматом приведет к неприятностям... ?

Comment: Чтобы по разному обрабатывать функции с похожими сигнатурами. В примере как раз та ситуация, когда передаются указатели на разные функции с одинаковым возвращаемым значением и аргументами.
[Ссылка на код для разъяснения](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O4Qo4bA5Ss9UPX15)

Comment: Сам же  на свой вопрос и ответил. [Следующий код](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DQ60pARXqw1dluFS) более менее решает мою проблему. Конечно криво, но это уже третье дело:)

Comment: Сигнатура функции это по сути тип, а тип один. Как вы можете впихнуть другой тип в функцию? Можно только другой экземпляр этого типа передать в функцию. Экземпляры сравнивают по адресу.

Comment: Что-то у меня по ссылке ничего не видно, никакого кода... Да вы бы пояснили исходную сверхзадачу, а то ощущение XY-проблемы. Может, есть какое-то очень простое решение, позволяющее добиться того, что вам нужно.

Comment: Вся моя сверхзадача состоит из того, чтобы различать разные функции переданные через указатель. Я ее уже решил, однако остался общий вопрос по выделению сигнатуры. Код из ссылки для разъяснения `void foo(void(*ptr)()){
 ptr();
}

int main(){
 void(*ptr)() = [](){};
 foo(ptr);
 ptr = [](){};
 foo(ptr);
}`.

Comment: Да, простое решение найдено, нужно было сравнить адреса.

Comment: *"остался общий вопрос по выделению сигнатуры"* Сделайте `foo` шаблоном?

Comment: Шаблоном можно сделать функцию с известным числом аргументов, для неизвестного числа нельзя, потому и пытаюсь получить сигнатуру